# Pasta repos não aparece as pastas do meu código (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todas estas pastas estão dentro do meu visual studio, estou tentando passar para o github mas na hora que acesso **"Source > Repos"** elas não existem lá

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o que posso fazer para resolver?

Comment: você vai ter que copiar para lá e fazer o commit para o repositório... mas você sabe que os seus projetos não precisam ficar lá para sincronizar com o git, certo? Não adianta só copiar a o sln...

Comment: Sim entendo, mas as pastas não aparecem no meu REPOS, não consigo nem zipar elas pra nada, como posso copiar as pastas?

Comment: Como assim? você já commitou no git? configurou o repo para o diretório, fez o checkout e não baixou nada?

Comment: Ps.: você commitou todos os arquivos do diretório ou apenas o .sln?